# SQL counting open items on records each month while it still not approved

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a calendar table which is this.

```
c_calendardate
1/1/2015
2/3/2015
.
.
.
10/18/2015
10/19/2015
```

and a transaction record on the material request.

```
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| Requestor  |   Item     | Date_Entry  | Approver  |  Status  |
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| Bob        | PCB        | 1/2/2015    | Admin     | Open     |
| Bob        | PCB        | 3/19/2015   | Admin     | Approved |
| May        | UTP Cable  | 1/1/2015    | Admin     | Open     |
| May        | UTP Cable  | 4/20/2015   | Admin     | Approved |
| Joseph     | RJ45       | 2/10/2015   | Admin     | Open     |
| Joseph     | RJ46       | 6/3/2015    | Admin     | Approved |
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

and what output I want is this.

```
+------------+-----------------------+
|   Month    | Total_Open_Each_Month |
+------------+-----------------------+
| 2015-Jan   |                     2 |
| 2015-Feb   |                     3 |
| 2015-Mar   |                     3 |
| 2015-Apr   |                     2 |
| 2015-May   |                     1 |
| 2015-Jun   |                     1 |
| 2015-Jul   |                     0 |
| 2015-Aug   |                     0 |
| 2015-Sept  |                     0 |
| 2015-Oct   |                     0 |
| 2015-Nov   |                     0 |
| 2015-Dec   |                     0 |
+------------+-----------------------+
```

The output above is to count each open items each month and will still be counted on each month if the record is still not being approved, can anyone help me on the query?

Comment: you have a transaction *row* that is xml or html like in a db?

Comment: @espongha, I took a leap of faith and converted your HTML tables into ascii tables. If that's not what you intended, rollback the edit.

Comment: DId you do something already? And why do you need c_calendardate table? It is one table select, group by date_format and count.

Comment: @vhu thanks I having a hard time to edit the table

Comment: @Anthon M., I need to show the open items each month for a one year report so I'm thinking I need to reference this to a calendar table, do you a good advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT()` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
 DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(c_calendardate,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%b'), 
 COUNT(status) 
FROM yourcalendar 
 LEFT JOIN materialrequest on (c_calendardate=Date_Entry AND status='Open')
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(c_calendardate,'%m/%d/%Y'),'%Y-%b');
```

Comment: thanks for responding on my question, but this query count only the open items on the that month only, what I need is the items will still be counted on each month while it still not being approved.

Comment: Do you mean that Bob's PCB requested in January should count AS open item against all months since `Date_Entry` until today (`NOW()`) - e.g. against Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep and Oct?

Comment: if you reference on my table Bob PCB request should be counted on Jan, Feb until Mar as the Bob PCB request has been approved by the admin at 3/19/2015 and will not be counted on Apr onwards.

Comment: What should be done with items that do not have approval?

Comment: it will still be counted until today( NOW() ).

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this way

```
SELECT count(id),
STR_TO_DATE(Date_Entry, '%m/%d/%Y') as date1
MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(Date_Entry, '%m/%d/%Y') ),
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(Date_Entry, '%m/%d/%Y') )
FROM
Table_name
WHERE
Status =  'open'
group by date1
```